# Firefox is caching GWT.nocache.js even with no-cache headers

Tags: firefox, gwt, caching

I'm having troubles with firefox caching using GWT, if I deploy site second time, FF on page load will use cached .nocache.js, which can't load page logics, so I will see blank screen. I tried to set headers as it was described [here](http://seewah.blogspot.ru/2009/02/gwt-tips-2-nocachejs-getting-cached-in.html), but FF is still caching, but not on hard drive, but in memory. Changing

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ModuleName/ModuleName.nocache.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="ModuleName/ModuleName.nocache.js?v=90?"></script>
```

will help, but it's not comfortable to change parameter each time I'm deploying. Using Tomcat7, GWT 2.5.1, FF 23.0.1.

What i got after second deploy with header filter: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/vwn0.jpg/ . As you can see, headers are setted but FF is still caching  .nocache.js in memory and using it.

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Strange, I use almost exact same code and it works for me. Are you sure that your filter gets invoked?

Comment: Strange... Solutions can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files

Comment: @Naturlih: did you check the headers are correctly sent? (in Firefox developer tools)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: I've updated post, as you can see headers are setted correctly, FF is using expired cache.